# How to prove that this sequence is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

How can I prove that $f_n(x)=\left|x-\frac12\right|^{(n+1)/n}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $C^1[0,1]$ with sup norm? It seems obvious when we look at graphs but I need this formal way.I need this for my proof that $C^1[0,1]$ with sup norm is not a Banach space.